# How can I determine storage directory from ADB?

Tags: adb, storage

Is there a way I can use ADB to determine the external storage directory (equivalent of the Android API call `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`adb shell echo $EXTERNAL_STORAGE`.  All credit goes to Flow for leading me to experiment and find this.

Naturally you can use `cd $EXTERNAL_STORAGE` or whatever else you might need during an adb shell session or from a terminal emulator.

Comment: Good Teamwork :) +1

Comment: Very good! Thanks! Note, though, that if you may need to escape $ depending on your shell. example: adb shell echo \$EXTERNAL_STORAGE

Comment: Hmm, it turns out that my samsung vibrant gives me a different value for $EXTERNAL_STORAGE than it does Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(). This isn't the first nasty bug I've found on this phone.

Comment: @stephelton That's disappointing.  Which one's incorrect?  $EXTERNAL_STORAGE is correct for me, `/mnt/sdcard/external_sd/`.

Answer (score 6):

**<strike>I don't think that this is possible.</strike> See [Matthew's Post](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/14105/how-can-i-determine-storage-directory-from-adb/14109#14109)**

But let's have a lock on how `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` returns the external storage directory. A quick look in `android/os/Environment.java` shows that all this method does, is returning a static constant File member called `EXTERNAL_STORAGE_DIRECTORY`. This constant is initialized by

```
private static final File EXTERNAL_STORAGE_DIRECTORY
        = getDirectory("EXTERNAL_STORAGE", "/sdcard");
```

which calls `getDirectory()`

```
static File getDirectory(String variableName, String defaultPath) {
    String path = System.getenv(variableName);
    return path == null ? new File(defaultPath) : new File(path);
}
```

So the external storage directory is nothing else then an java System environment variable (or a predefined default). You could try to follow this trace further. Maybe the external storage directory is just a hard coded path in some configuration file on the filesystem. Or maybe there is a way to read out these environment variables via `adb` that I don't know.

Comment: I figured out the adb command using this info, +1.